# Password hash in IPB 4

Tags: php, hash, passwords, password-encryption, ipb

I am using IPB 4 forum platform for my community and I want to make a portal that uses the forums user/password combo
The problem is that I cant figure out how to hash the password when logging in

I've tried this

```
function ipbhash($salt, $password){
    return crypt($password, '$2a$13$' . $salt);
}

function ipbhash($salt, $password){
    return  md5(md5($salt) . md5($password));
}
```

But still no luck

Comment: I really hope they are using the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to store the passwords, in this case you could use the function [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check the password at login. Directly calculating the hash for comparison should not be possible, because of the salt.